# How to set Jenkins to use system's Date, Time, Number, and Currency formats?

Tags: java, jenkins, jvm, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running some date time format verification test in Jenkins. I want to use Sweden date, time ,number and currency formats. Although I change the OS date, time, number and currency formats to Sweden format, Jenkins use US formats in date, time, number and currency. But when I change the time zone of the OS, Jenkins takes that time zone. My problem is how to set Jenkins to take OS date, time, number and currency formats?

I've change the java.locale.provides, user.country. But it doesn't work either.